# Explicit template instantiation example

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am currently reading a book and it has the following example:

```
//ch4_4_class_template_explicit.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template < typename T > //line A
  struct A {
    A(T init): val(init) {}
    virtual T foo();
    T val;
  }; //line B
//line C
template < class T > //T in this line is template parameter
  T A < T > ::foo() { //the 1st T refers to function return type,
    //the T in <> specifies that this function's template
    //parameter is also the class template parameter
    return val;
  } //line D
extern template struct A < int > ; //line E
#if 0 //line F
int A < int > ::foo() {
  return val + 1;
}
#endif //line G
int main(void) {
  A < double > x(5);
  A < int > y(5);
  cout << "fD=" << x.foo() << ",fI=" << y.foo() << endl;
  return 0; //output: fD=5,fI=6
}
```

Can someone explain to me what the line

```
extern template struct A < int > ;
```

does and why the second definition for `foo()`?
I understand what explicit template instantiation is and why it is sometimes useful, but the use of `extern` is not really clear to me.

The book has the following explanation for this line:

*Using the extern keyword prevents implicit instantiations of that function template (see
the next section for more details).*

So `extern` prevents us from doing the following?:

```
auto obj = A<int>;
```

The second definition then negates the extern? I really can't understand this example.

Edit 1: added commented code.

Edit 2:
I am almost sure that my understanding is correct. But thanks for answering.

Explanation from the book:
*In the preceding code block, we defined a class template between lines A and B, and then
we implemented its member function, foo(), from lines C to line D. Next, we explicitly
instantiated it for the int type at line E. Since the code block between lines F and line
G is commented out (which means that there is no corresponding definition of foo() for
this explicit int type instantiation), we have a linkage error. To fix this, we need to replace
#if 0 with #if 1 at line F.*

Comment: It is a bad example, because it does not even compile: https://godbolt.org/z/a99bcncEW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help you to unsderstand.

From the C++ 20 (13.9.2 Explicit instantiation)

> 2 The syntax for explicit instantiation is:

```
explicit-instantiation:
    externopt template declaration
```

> There are two forms of explicit instantiation: an explicit
> instantiation definition and an explicit instantiation declaration. An
> explicit instantiation declaration begins with the extern keyword.

So this line

```
extern template struct A < int > ;
```

is an explicit instantiation declaration of the class specialization `struct A<int>`.